# Build HTML from JSON (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I am trying to get data from a url or a local file and display that in a div. My json url would be https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts. I am trying to get the data into my divs but dont know how? Then my code so far is:

**JS**

```
var HttpClient = function() {
    this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
        var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
        }

        anHttpRequest.open( "GET", aUrl, true );            
        anHttpRequest.send( null );
    }
}


var url = new HttpClient();
url.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', function(response) {

});
```

**HTML structure for data: four columns layout with span**

```
 <div class="inside">
          <div class="sml_image"></div>
          <p class="title"></p>
          <p class="sub"></p>
          <p class="body"></p>
     </div>
```

Comment: Please don't downvote the answers that actually answer your question.

Comment: I didnt downvote you mate, maybe by error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't see any image url in that json, I've put the id instead in the div with class `.image`, I've made you an example on how you can do it. You can do it like this, using `JSON.parse` to convert the response string into an object, a loop and `innerHMTL`:

```js
var HttpClient = function() {
   this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
     var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
     anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
         aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
     }

     anHttpRequest.open("GET", aUrl, true);
     anHttpRequest.send(null);
   }
 }


 var url = new HttpClient();
 url.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', function(response) {
   var json = JSON.parse(response);
   for (var x = 0; x < json.length; x++) {
     document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += '<div class="inside"><div class="image">'+ json[x].id +'</div><p class="title">' + json[x].title + '</p><p class="body">' + json[x].body + '</p></div>';
   }
 });
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

Ok. So after discussing with the OP, we've came up to the solution to change what's in innerHTML a bit:

```
document.getElementById("slide").innerHTML += '<span><div class="inner"><div class="inner_image" id="image_url_' + x + '"></div><div class="inner_box"><div class="thumb"><img src="' + json[x].image + '" class="thumb" alt="thumb"></div><p class="title" id="title_' + x + '">' + json[x].title + '</p><p class="sub_text" id="author_' + x + '"></p><p class="body" id="text_' + x  + '">' + json[x].body + '</p></div></div></span>';
```

Comment: How would I get the data into different divs though? in my json url there is a image. Rather than like just container. I would like it in different ones.

Comment: At the moment it just goes into container. But i want the title to go in the <div id="title"></div> and the rest like <div id="body"></div> etc

Comment: Sorry i didn't downvote the answer, maybe by mistake

Comment: What do you mean by different divs. It's already being created multiple divs. Do you mean like you want all titles to go into the a single div with class `title` and all body resullts to go into a single element with class `body`?

Comment: Yes that would be the way

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that? I would recommend you to use the way from my answer. That is the right way to do it. Otherwise as you want, all the titles and body texts would be mixed up.

Comment: Because there is a 4 column layout which needs the data to go in each box

Comment: Please post the markup with the four columns and rows if you have then by updating your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130899/discussion-between-ionut-and-sole).

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSON and set up a loop to construct the HTML:

```js
var HttpClient = function() {
  this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
    var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
        aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
    }

    anHttpRequest.open("GET", aUrl, true);
    anHttpRequest.send(null);
  }
}


var url = new HttpClient();
url.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', function(response) {

  /* ANSWER */

  var items = JSON.parse(response);
  var container = document.getElementById('container');

  items.forEach(function (item) {
    var div = newElement('div');

    div.appendChild(newElement('p', 'title', item.title));
    div.appendChild(newElement('p', 'body', item.body));
    
    container.appendChild(div);
  })

  /* END ANSWER */

});

function newElement(tag, className, content) {
  var el = document.createElement(tag);
  if (className) el.className = className;
  if (content) el.innerHTML = content;
  return el;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```